# Javascript $ reference error

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and jQuery and I am the code below is from Jquery and Javascript. My problem is that when I run this code, I am getting an error in my error console which says :

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined.
```

I have no idea why it is not recognizing the $ sign.

```
 <link href="../_css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="../_js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
      <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').hide().fadeIn(3000);
  });
  </script>
  </head>
```

Comment: Look at the [console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console). the jQuery script is probably not found.

Comment: Can you tell us the location of the `jquery-1.7.2.min.js` in your application?

Comment: Are you sure that jQuery is really at `../_js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js` and loads properly?

Comment: Is the source valid? I like to use google's gziped file. Lot quicker for downloading ;) `src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"`.

Comment: It's probably due to `jquery` included in the page was not loaded . Can you please look at the net console in firebug or chrome .

Comment: I have opened the console and it is empty. How do you check if the jquery script is there or not?

Comment: Actually I just found a file in my index folder called jquery.min.js

Comment: open a new tab and just to to navigate to the jquery file location and see if it matches what you have... e.g. http://www.example.com/_js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Comment: @MrD , I took the link and searched it, it doest point ot the jquery library. So I then used what Beneto suggested, and although I am pointing to the jquery file now, the code is not dispalying anything.

Comment: @Stranger do you still get the error in the console?

Comment: Yes, it says the following: The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document with render with garbled text in some browser configurations......

Comment: You can prevent that warning message by adding `<meta charset=utf-8">` at the very beginning of the head section, although it probably won't get jQuery working.

Comment: If I run in chrome it tells me the following now: Failed to load the resource : file:///C:/Users/mike/_css/site.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are loading the jQuery library.  Substitute this for your local jquery reference:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also `../` at the beginning of both the CSS and jQuery references references the parent directory.  If the files subdirectories are in the same directory as the referencing `html` file remove `../`

Comment: I tried that link and it tells me : Failed to load the reource

Comment: If you put the google jquery URL in your browser does it load?

Comment: Do you have a `<!DOCTYPE html>` declaration at the beginning of the page?  Are you working with a local file vs. through local (or remote) webserver?

Comment: I dont have the <DOCTYPE> declaration and I am working with a local file @shaun5